# How to create a rule for Backus Naur Form in c++?-

Tags: c++, algorithm, bnf

I am new in BNF and I really don't know/understand how to make a rule and how to check it on c++. I seen some example but no explanation how it works and how the rule checks the input;

for example our teacher give this example to our  lesson,

```
<palindrome>::=<empty>|a|b|a<palindrome>a|b<palindrome>b

sample input: abba

how it checks:
<empty>

a<palindrome>a

ab<palindrome>a
abba
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that if you have a question about the exact details of your assignment, the best person to ask for help would be your teachers. That's their job, and that's what they get paid for. BNF is a very broad topic, and it is completely unclear what exactly you're looking for, a bison/yacc ruleset, or an explanation of the BNF syntax, or something else entirely, so any response you get here will be guesswork, at best. So your best course of action is to ask your teachers for assistance with your assignment, as I said, after all, that's their job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Boost.Spirit X3.  For that you'd have to rewrite your rule a little because Boost.Spirit stops parsing as soon as it finds something matching, i.e. in the string `abba` it would match `a` and stop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

auto const a = x3::char_('a');
auto const b = x3::char_('b');
auto const aa = x3::lit("aa");
auto const bb = x3::lit("bb");

x3::rule<class palindrome> const palindrome = "palindrome";
auto const palindrome_def
    = a >> palindrome >> a
    | b >> palindrome >> b
    | aa
    | bb
    | a
    | b;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(palindrome);

int main() {
    std::string input = "abba";
    auto first = input.begin();
    auto last = input.end();

    bool r = parse(first, last, palindrome);

    if (!r || first != last) {
        std::cerr << "Parsing failed at " << std::string{first,last} << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Success :)\n";
}
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EuBLivTXd05vHi04)